# grid.ajaxRequest() not passing parameters

Tags: javascript, asp.net-mvc, telerik-grid

I have a javascript function which on click of a button rebinds the data source to the telerik grid. The function works good and hits the controller. However, it does not pass the required parameter value and instead shows a null.

The code for javascript is:

```
        $("#btnclick").click(function () {
        console.log("Clicked");
        var grid = $("#UploadList").data("tGrid");
        var params = {
            Idss: "SampleId"
        };

        grid.ajaxRequest(params);

    })
```

The code for controller is:

```
        [GridAction]

    public ActionResult List(string Idss)
    {
        string passedId = Idss;
        try
        {
```

By putting a break point I check the value for Idss or passedId, it always shows null instead of SampleId.

Any help would be appreciated.

Answer (score 0):

I found the solution. In order to pass the params we should use `grid.rebind(params)` instead of `grid.ajaxRequest(params)`.

useful link: https://docs.telerik.com/aspnet-mvc/migration/widgets/grid